# Installing ELAN 5.1 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, software-installation, java

I'm currently trying to install a [QDA software called ELAN (v 5.1)](https://tla.mpi.nl/tools/tla-tools/elan/) on Ubuntu 17.10 in the following manner:

1. The install page states that the software requires Java Runtime Environment, which I installed prior to installing ELAN from [Oracle's Java pages, following their instructions.](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml).
2. I then dowloaded the [`.bin`](http://www.mpi.nl/tools/elan/ELAN_5-1_linux.bin) file and then ran the installation from terminal `./ELAN_5-1_linux.bin`.
3. A graphical UI pops up, and I just followed the instructions and installed ELAN to my home folder, seemingly without problems.
4. I ran the program (`./ELAN_5.1` inside the folder), but it won't start. However, I get the following output:

   ```
   raw jre dir: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
   jre dir: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/user/ELAN_5.1/jmf__Vlin2.1.1fcs:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/i386/xawt:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/i386/client:
   LD_PRELOAD:
   ```

Then nothing happens. No error messages, just returns to command line.
I did however notice some anomaly: There is no `i386` folder inside `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/`. **The paths**

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/i386
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/i386/xawt
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/i386/client
```

therefore **does not exist**. I assume failure to add the correct paths to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may be related to the failure to start ELAN. ..and shouldn't `LD_PRELOAD` be followed by a path?

Any input on what is causing the issue and how to solve it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on The Language Archive's forum pages.
[This post presented a workaround](https://tla.mpi.nl/topic/installing-elan-5-1-in-ubuntu-17-10/#post-12115), that enables me to start the program. Seemingly it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I eventually followed to install ELAN 5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. (Sorry I didn't record all the error messages I got doing it without these steps.)

1. Download ELAN_5-2_linux.bin from https://tla.mpi.nl/tools/tla-tools/elan/download/
2. As root: `# apt install openjdk-8-jre vlc`
3. As root, edit `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties` to comment out the 1 line that's not already a comment
4. As regular user, `$ chmod a+x ELAN_5-2_linux.bin` then `$ ./ELAN_5-2_linux.bin` and follow the prompts to install into a directory
5. As regular user, in the directory thus created, `$ ./ELAN_5.2`

Answer (score 0):

Today I installed ELAN using their (presumably new?) `.deb` package. It can be found on [The Language Archive's download page](https://tla.mpi.nl/tools/tla-tools/elan/download/) – just scroll down to ‘Elan for Linux’ and click the ‘[.deb]’ link there.

After that you should be able to install it with `dpkg`, like so:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/ELAN_5-5-FX_linux.deb
```

P.S. I’m running Lubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) and installed ELAN 5.5, and I did not have to install any dependencies before installing running the above `dpkg` command.